# Kubuntu 18.04 Asus Rog Strix z370-I Gaming Bluetooth Not Working

Tags: drivers, kubuntu, bluetooth, 18.04

I'm having issues with Bluetooth on Fresh Kubuntu 18.04 install on Z370-I Gaming Motherboard that has integrated wireless bear in mind wireless worked out of the box while Bluetooth can not seem to find adapter.

> `systemctl status bluetooth`

```
bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2018-05-25 10:08:40 CEST; 2h 23min ago
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
 Main PID: 852 (bluetoothd)
   Status: "Running"
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
           └─852 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd
```

> `lspci`

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 3ec2 (rev 07)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 3e92
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH USB 3.0 xHCI Controller
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH CSME HECI #1
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH SATA controller [AHCI mode]
00:1b.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port #17 (rev f0)
00:1b.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port #20 (rev f0)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f0)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f0)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f0)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device a2c9
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH PMC
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH HD Audio
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH SMBus Controller
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V
02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device b822
04:00.0 USB controller: ASMedia Technology Inc. Device 2142
```

> `lsusb`

```
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 413c:2113 Dell Computer Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 2516:002b  
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0b05:185c ASUSTek Computer, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0b05:1872 ASUSTek Computer, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

When I try to manually start it via `bluetoothctl` I get following:

```
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# power on
No default controller available
[bluetooth]#
```

Also the output of `rfkill` is:

```
ID TYPE      DEVICE      SOFT      HARD
 0 wlan      phy0   unblocked unblocked
 1 bluetooth hci0   unblocked unblocked
```

Any help would be most welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem with fresh installed Kubuntu 18.04 and Asus Rog Strix Z370-E. It turned out that the stock 4.15 kernel in bionic has all necessary drivers and firmware shipped, but doesn't yet recognise the device (0b05:185c) as r8822be bluetooth adapter (kernel 4.17 does). Resulting in the needed firmware files not being loaded.

What I did to resolve this:

- Download Kernel source

  ```
   apt-get source linux-source-4.15.0
  ```
- Copy the content of "linux-4.15.0/drivers/bluetooth/" to "~/btusb-custom/" (I wanted to keep the original code for reference in case I did something wrong.)
- edit ~/btusb-custom/btusb.c and add the rtl8822be hardware-IDs around line 376. Change from:

  ```
      /* Additional Realtek 8821AE Bluetooth devices */
      { USB_DEVICE(0x0b05, 0x17dc), .driver_info = BTUSB_REALTEK },
      { USB_DEVICE(0x13d3, 0x3414), .driver_info = BTUSB_REALTEK },
      { USB_DEVICE(0x13d3, 0x3458), .driver_info = BTUSB_REALTEK },
      { USB_DEVICE(0x13d3, 0x3461), .driver_info = BTUSB_REALTEK },
      { USB_DEVICE(0x13d3, 0x3462), .driver_info = BTUSB_REALTEK },

      /* Silicon Wave based devices */
      { USB_DEVICE(0x0c10, 0x0000), .driver_info = BTUSB_SWAVE },

      { } /* Terminating entry */
  ```

  to:

  ```
      /* Additional Realtek 8821AE Bluetooth devices */
      { USB_DEVICE(0x0b05, 0x17dc), .driver_info = BTUSB_REALTEK },
      { USB_DEVICE(0x13d3, 0x3414), .driver_info = BTUSB_REALTEK },
      { USB_DEVICE(0x13d3, 0x3458), .driver_info = BTUSB_REALTEK },
      { USB_DEVICE(0x13d3, 0x3461), .driver_info = BTUSB_REALTEK },
      { USB_DEVICE(0x13d3, 0x3462), .driver_info = BTUSB_REALTEK },

      /* Additional Realtek 8822BE Bluetooth devices */
      { USB_DEVICE(0x13d3, 0x3526), .driver_info = BTUSB_REALTEK },
      { USB_DEVICE(0x0b05, 0x185c), .driver_info = BTUSB_REALTEK },

      /* Silicon Wave based devices */
      { USB_DEVICE(0x0c10, 0x0000), .driver_info = BTUSB_SWAVE },

      { } /* Terminating entry */
  ```

(code taken from https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/bluetooth/btusb.c )

- Also in btusb.c change line 41 from:

  ```
  #define VERSION "0.8"
  ```

  to:

  ```
  #define VERSION "0.8-custom"
  ```

  (Otherwise you would have to force dkms install.)
- Create "~/btusb-custom/dkms.conf", with following content:

  ```
      PACKAGE_NAME="btusb-custom"
      PACKAGE_VERSION=0.1
      CLEAN="make clean"
      BUILT_MODULE_NAME[0]="btusb"
      DEST_MODULE_NAME[0]="btusb"
      DEST_MODULE_LOCATION[0]="/updates"
      REMAKE_INITRD=yes
      AUTOINSTALL=yes
  ```
- After that, I installed my customized module with DKMS:

  ```
  sudo dkms add ~/btusb_custom
  sudo dkms install btusb-custom/0.1
  ```
- And tested with

  ```
  sudo modprobe -r btusb
  sudo modprobe btusb
  ```

**Viola! The bluetooth tray-icon in KDE instantly popped up.**

```
    dmesg | grep 8822
```

results in

```
    ...
    [    3.629464] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: examining hci_ver=07 hci_rev=000b lmp_ver=07 lmp_subver=8822
    [    3.629465] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: loading rtl_bt/rtl8822b_config.bin
    [    3.630645] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: loading rtl_bt/rtl8822b_fw.bin
    ...
```

Dont forget to remove that module as soon as you get a kernel upgrade >= 4.17, you won't need it from there on.

NOTE: My kernel-development-knowledge is about zero, all of above code is copy&paste from various search results combined with some common sense - if something I wrote is bad advice, please correct me!!

Answer (score 1):

As an update (because I ran into this issue as well), you can download the 4.17 pre-built packages from Canonicals PPA [here](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.17/). Download the `generic` variants of modules, image, and headers, then `dpkg -i` the three of them and reboot. Doing this fixed my BT issues :)